# Node.js only one function executed

Tags: node.js, function, execution

I try to execute two functions in a post request but only one is triggered. The function makeEntry executes but the function afterwards renderEntries does'nt. Can anyone help pls?
Here is the code: https://codepaste.net/bpsxsy

Comment: Could you please provide more information? Any errors you may get? Does this happen when the user is not logged in?

Comment: If the user is not logged in, send() will executed and the response is done without renderEntries(). But renderEntries also does'nt execute if the user is logged in, res.send() are not executed.

Comment: Ok, both functions executes but the entries only render on get request not on post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to how callbacks work in Javascript. Here is the part which matters:

```
  app.post('/guestbook_post', urlencodedparser, function(req, res){
    makeEntry(req, res, Guestbook);
    renderEntries(res, Guestbook);
  });
```

You pass `res` to both functions. But `makeEntry` invokes `res.send()` which means it will end the request and send the response back to the client. However, `renderEntries` was not yet executed, but still waiting in event loop.  It will be executed the next time you make a post request, which will lead to very confusing and buggy behaviour.

To make it work as intendeed, refactor functions `makeEntry` and `renderEntries` to **return** the needed result object and render it to the client once. Something like this:

```
  app.post('/guestbook_post', urlencodedparser, function(req, res){
    makeEntry(req, Guestbook, (err, entry) => {
        renderEntries(entry, Guestbook, (err, result) => {
            res.send(result);
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thx but res.send() will not executed if the user is logged in.

Comment: That's another question you may raise separately. Please mark this question as "accepted" if it solves the problem of "only one function executed".